# How to create a new column that consecutively sums from another column in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a data table with 3 columns: customer_id, time_period and bought_cookies (0 if no, 1 if yes). I want to create a new column (total_number_cookie_buyers) that sums the previous rows of bought_cookies to see how many people have bought cookies up to that point in time (e.g. if the first three rows of bought_cookies were 0, 1, 0 then the value in the third row of total_number_cookie_buyers would be 1). I've tried googling but can't find anything on how to do this!

Comment: Please [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including some example data in a plain text format.

Comment: Look at the ‘rollapply’ function in the ‘zoo’ package. This is a convenient and easy to use method for cumulative calculations over a data frame.

Comment: Maybe you just need `cumsum` by group. If you have `data.table` something like this should work, `dt[, total_number_cookie_buyers := cumsum(bought_cookies), customer_id]` Or maybe just `dt[, total_number_cookie_buyers := cumsum(bought_cookies)]`

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are looking for is called cumulative sum.
I think it is the solution.

```
cust_id <- NULL
 for(i in 1:21){
  if(i<10){ k <- paste("ID_00",i,sep="") } else{
    k <- paste("ID_0",i,sep="") }
  cust_id[i] <- k 
}
date <- sample(seq(as.Date('2020/01/01'), as.Date('2020/01/21'), by="day"), 21)
date <- date[order(date)]
sales <- rbinom(21,1,0.5)
df <- data.frame(cust_id=cust_id,date=date,sales=sales)
df$salesydate <- cumsum(df$sales)
```

cust_id       date   sales    salesdate

1   ID_001 2020-01-01     0          0

2   ID_002 2020-01-02     0          0

3   ID_003 2020-01-03     0          0

4   ID_004 2020-01-04     1          1

5   ID_005 2020-01-05     1          2

6   ID_006 2020-01-06     0          2

7   ID_007 2020-01-07     1          3

...................................

Comment: The solution is really only the final line of code `df$salesydate <- cumsum(df$sales)`, the rest is just to build an example data set. You should separate the two and label them so the OP, who is a beginner, knows which is which.